# php cant recognize pdo objects in other methods

Tags: php, pdo, binding

when i want to use `$this->stmt->bindValue()` in a bindvalue php storm gives error:

> method bindvalue not found in PDO

and when i run the codes i see this error:

> "PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\oop\app\Model\DB.php on line 54

```
<?php  namespace App\Model;


class DB
{

    /**
     * @var PDO   <--- need by PhpStorm to find Methods of PDO
     */

    protected  $table ;
    /**
     * @var PDO   <--- need by PhpStorm to find Methods of PDO
     */
    protected $stmt ;
    protected $bind=[] ;
    protected $fetchMode = \PDO::FETCH_OBJ ;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $config= require_once (__DIR__.'/../config.php') ;


        try{
            $this->pdo = new \PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname={$config['db']['database']}",$config['db']['username']
,$config['db']['password']) ;

        } catch (\Exception $e)
        {
            die($e->getMessage());
        }

    } // end of constructor

    public  function select()
    {

        $stmt = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM  {$this->table}") ;
        $stmt->execute();
      return  $stmt->fetchAll() ;

    } // end of select method

    public function create($data)
    {
        $field = join(',',array_keys($data)) ;
        $param = ':'. join(', :' , array_keys($data)) ;

        $this->stmt =  $this->pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO $this->table ($field) VALUES ($param)") ;
        $this->bind = $data ;

        $this->bindValue() ;

        return $this->stmt->execute();

    }

    public function bindValue()
    {

        var_dump($this->stmt);
        foreach ($this->bind as $key => $value){
            $this->stmt->bindValue(":$key " , $value) ; //error
        }

    }


} // end of DB class
```

Comment: Learn how to __debug__.

Comment: You should carefully read about parameterized queries on the PHP documentation. What you are currently doing is constructing a query without parameters, and then binding values to those non-existent parameters. Hence the error message.

Comment: Not sure if the space in `":$key "` is significant.

Answer (score 0):

> method bindvalue not found in PDO

This is correct. The *PDO* class represents the connection to the database, not the individual query/statement. For that there is the *PDOStatement* class.

Comment: what should i do? this code works in my friends project.exactly same codes he use

Comment: Syntactically, your code is correct. Why it doesn't work for you we can't see from this snippet.